# How to implement a custom actionbar and set a resizable title to it in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-xml

I created a custom actionbar so that I can add buttons to the actionbar. But now I need a way to display the title of the app on this custom actionbar. I have a temporary fix by adding a TextView to my custom actionbar but I don't want to be re-sizing it for different devices (such as tablets and phone). See is what it looks it so far:

[image]

This title is too small. I want it to match the size of the buttons. Here is my code for the custom actionbar xml:

**actionbar_custom.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_backspace_white_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/customTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnBack"
        android:text="App Title" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnHelp"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_help_white_24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions? Let me know if more detail is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to the `TextView`tag: `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`